# Add if statement to a class in php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the following code:

```
<?php if ( is_post_extra_title_meta_enabled() ) { ?>
<div class="post-header">
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'd like to make the class H1 IF it is on the frontpage/homepage in wordpress.  How would I add an if/else command to this? So basically:

```
If on front page:
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

Else:
 <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine if you're on the home page in wordpress, you can use the [`is_home()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/) function.

So if you're looking to add an if else inside the original if statement you provided, your code would go as such,

```
<?php if ( is_post_extra_title_meta_enabled() ) { ?>
    <div class="post-header">
        <?php if ( is_home() ) { ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php else { ?>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm biased towards using the alternative syntax, so here's the code rewritten.

```
<?php if ( is_post_extra_title_meta_enabled() ): ?>
    <div class="post-header">
        <?php if ( is_home() ): ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else: ?>
            <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your WP configuration you might use is_front_page() or is_home() (as Ryan mentioned)